# Translate google translate return result which is Percent-encoding

Tags: google-api

I am trying to translate my input text to Tamil from English. For that i have used the following snippet.

```
<form id="Master_form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body" style="padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:2px">
            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:15px">

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="enText" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="tnText" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $("#enText").keyup(function () {
        var id = $('#enText').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Translate")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (result) {
                //var res =unescapeUTF8EscapeSeq(result);
                $('#tnText').val(res);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And the code behind is

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Foo(string id)
        {
            Translate trans = new Translate();
            trans.engText = "";
            trans.tmText = "";
            var langpair = "en%7Cta#en/ta/" + id;
            string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", id, langpair);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
            result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
            //result = UnescapeHex(result);
            return Json(result.Trim(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When i type SARA it was returned the result as `&#2970;&#3006;&#2992;&#3006;`.
when it paste it in google it was shown the translated text. But in application it is not converted.

Kindly provide your valuable ideas to sort out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by bind the value in textarea and it shows the decoded text.

```
   $("#" + src).keyup(function () {
        //$("#" + src).change(function () {
            var id = $('#' + src).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Translate")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: { 'id': id },
                success: function (result) {
                    //var res =unescapeUTF8EscapeSeq(result);
                    //$('#tnText').val(res);
                    //$('#tnText').val(result);
                    $('#' + dest).val(decodeEntities(result));
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error occured');
                }
            });
        })


function decodeEntities(input) {
    var y = document.createElement('textarea');
    y.innerHTML = input;
    return y.value;
}
```